# IP pkt len in ESP transport mode? How to validate ESP pad length?

Tags: security, ipsec

What will be the value of packet-length/Total length field in the IP headers for ESP packets in  transport mode?
For instance, in tunnel mode below are the values:-

> Outer-IP header's Packet length = Size of application-data +
> Transport/L4-Header-length (TCP,UDP etc) + Original-IP-Header Length +
> ESP-Header + IV size + Padding-bytes + Size-of ESP-Footer(pad-length field +
> Next-protocol field) + size-of
> Integrity-Check-Value(ICV)/Authentication-data
>
> Inner-Original-IP Header's Packet length = Size of application-data +
> Transport/L4-Header-length (TCP,UDP etc) + Original-IP-Header Length

Now, my question is, what is the value of IP Header's packet-length field for ESP packets in Transport-mode ?

Is it :-

> 1. Original IP packet's length = Size of application-data +  Transport/L4-Header-length (TCP,UDP etc) + Original-IP-Header Length
>    (OR)
> 2. Original IP packet's length + ESP Header + IV + ESP Footer + size-of padding + size-of ICV

Also, when is the ESP-HDR and footer fields inserted ? Is it after constructing a full IP-PDU or is it inserted before encapsulating the "L4-HDR + App-data" into a IP Header ?

If IP packet-length is calculated as mentioned in case#1 above, then how to validate the length of the ESP pad-length field ? Say, if the peer sends a packet with pad-length incorrectly.

In case of tunnel-mode the pad-length can be validated as follows:-

encrypted-esp-data-length = esp-footer-memory-address - memory-address of the esp-data start.

actual-esp-pad length = encrypted-esp-data-length - ip-packet-length

if actual-esp-pad-length != pad-length received in the packet, then we can declare the pad-length is invalid.

But, in case of esp in transport-mode the original IP-packet's length is lost, so, we cannot validate if the pad-length received in the ESP packet is valid or not. So, trying to understand if am missing something here.

Comment: Note that RFC 4303 allows for TFC padding (see section 2.7), where your padding validation won't work (it's optional, though). Also, see section 2.4 regarding the structure and validation of the regular padding.

Comment: @ecdsa, Thanks for pointing out about TFC padding. What I understand from the RFC is that TFC is possible only when ESP is used in tunnel mode or when ESP-transport mode is used for UDP packets, where the original length of the IP packet is available in the headers. And you are right, the computation mentioned by me won't work to validate padding length.

Comment: But, again the problem is, the receiving side is dependent on the pad-length field to properly strip-off the padding and fetch the application data, when ESP-transport mode is used for TCP streams where the original payload size is not available. And, if the pad-length is corrupted. And as per RFC, TFC padding shouldn't be used with ESP-transport mode on TCP streams.

Comment: Why should the padding length be corrupted and in what way (it's a single byte after all and it's processed after verifying the ICV and decrypting the packet - or both concurrently with AEAD algorithms)? And as mentioned, the RFC specifies how the default padding must look like, so it can easily be verified.

Comment: The short answer is i ran into negative test scenario in protocol testing tool(codenomicon), where the test suite sends a wrong pad-length. 
Long answer:- In real life scenario, this can happen the endpoint-A is peering with end-point-B and lets say due to an implementation bug at endpoint-B, it sends wrong  pad-length say 200 instead of 2. So, on the receiving side endpoint-A, it can lead to memory corruption when we try to strip off the padding and give the payload to application.

Comment: You obviously have to take the total length of the payload into account when processing the padding. Other than that, the padding structure is again described in section 2.4.

Comment: But, ESP in transport mode(with TCP being the next header) won't have the information about the total length of payload before encryption!

Comment: That doesn't matter when processing the padding. What matters it the length of the ESP payload data.

Comment: But, how can we get the length of the ESP payload at the receiving end in a transport mode  for TCP ? IP-pkt-length will correspond to the length of the encrypted-payload + ESP HDR + ESP Footer. ESP header doesn't have a field for payload length. The info ESP has is SPI, Sequence number, IV, ESP-pad-length, ESP-next-header and ICV. And the TCP header contains only the size of the TCP header.

Comment: Why do you need an explicit field for that? The ESP overhead has a fixed length (some depending on the algorithms), so you can determine the ESP payload and its length easily. You need that anyway to decrypt it. The padding is only processed afterwards (i.e. based on the decrypted data, whose length you know exactly). The inner protocol doesn't matter at all at that point (unless you also want to consider TFC padding).